# A sequence with an infinite number of ones that converges to a limit not equal to one.

Tags: real-analysis

a.) A sequence with an infinite number of ones that converges to a limit not equal to one.

b.) A divergent sequence such that for every $n$ ∈ ℕ it is possible to find $n$ consecutive ones somewhere in the sequence.

I know that a is false because if a series converges to 2 and epsilon is 1/2, then 2 is not within 1/2 of ones, but am having trouble proving the general case.

Also, for b I know that if is false because for the first subset of the infinite set, it will converge to one but also don't know how to show the general case.

Comment: "*The* first subset of *the* infinite set..."? What does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

a) We're given in fact that there's asequence $\;\{a_n\}\;$ with a subsequence $\;\{a_{n_k}\}\;$ suck that $\;a_{n_k}=1\;\;\;\forall\,n_k\;$, and thus...

b) Try the sequence:

$$a_n=\begin{cases}1,&n=2^k\;,\;\;\text{for some natural}\;\;k\\{}\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$